# Is 'gonna' anachronistic in Sweeney Todd?

Tags: etymology, british-english

In one song the boy sings "nothing's gonna harm you". This struck me as odd because I was under the impression that "gonna" was a primarily American slang that was adopted by the English much later. As Sondheim was an American composer and lyricist it's an understandable mistake for him to make.
So I did a bit of research and found conflicting accounts of "gonna"s origin, but nothing that says whether "gonna" was in use in England at the time.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gonna) says it was around in 1917 (later than Sweeney Todd), but lists no location of origin.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gonna) says gonna goes all the way back to 1800ish in Scotland. This makes sense to me because first, due to heavy immigration from Scotland to the US, there are many Scottish words preserved in America. But again, Sweeney Todd is set in England, not Scotland.

The dates I've been working with for Sweeney Todd being in London are 1846–47 based on when the original story (string of pearls) was written.

Does anyone have evidence whether gonna was in use in London at the time? Or is this anachronistic?

Comment: I don't think it's a mistake for a songwriter to use language idiomatic to their audience.

Comment: Etymon says 'attempt to represent the casual pronunciation of _going to_'. The rendition in print/writing. The sound it represents is doubtless from far earlier times. Sondheim probably aims for accurate representation using the written word ... using today's usages.

Comment: There are no slangs. Slangs aren't things. Slang is not a count nount. And everybody says it that way. It's just a black mark against one's ejucashun to write it that way.

Comment: The entry for "gonna" in the OED, has no examples from England until 2010. Earlier than that, and the examples are American English or broad Scottish English.

Comment: "Gonna" sounds like a representation of a particular accent. In Australian it sounds more like "gunna" (and a "gunner" is somebody who is always "gunner" do something, but ...)"

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, I agree it's no mark against the work to use his audience's idioms. But it's funny that he sometimes uses English idioms and sometimes uses American. I wouldn't complain that Shakespeare wrote Julius Caesar in English rather than Latin. But what if he had tried to write Latin and threw in English here and there?

Comment: @Peter, I very much thought about spelling it "gunna", since that's how I pronounce it. But I went with "gonna" because that's how I see it written most often and that's what I searched for to get the results I did.

Comment: @tchrist, I don't think slang is a black Mark against anyone or anything. That doesn't mean it's not slang. Gonna is an abbreviated form of going to, which for a very long time was peculiar to Scottish and American English. That fits the definition of slang. That doesn't mean it's bad, of course, or that people who use gonna are somehow less educated. I'm gonna keep using gonna forever. But it's slang.

Comment: @JosephSummerhays You have cunfyoozed  speekun n riding.  Don't do that. It's a black mark against your ejukashun as I have all reddy esplaned you. No one will take you seriously in the professional realm if you cannot spell English the way they expect you to spell it. It doesn't matter one whit how you pronounce things. That simply is not how English works. Standard English is called that for a reason. If you do not wish for people to treat you in the same disrespectful way your spelling treats them, then you may need to reconsider. Itza yer choys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweeney Todd's usage of *gonna* is likely anachronistic. As your second source says, *gonna* dates to the 19th century, and initially appears in Scottish texts. Note the Oxford English Dictionary's first two sources for "[gonna, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79914)" are both in a Scottish dialect and use a distinct Scottish spelling ([a] or [au]):

> *colloquial*. 1. With auxiliary *be*: going to (see GO v. 51a(a)).
>
> 1806   A. Douglas Poems 70   Now, Willie lad, I'm ganna gie You twa or three directions.
>
> 1856   D. Pae Jessie Melville vii. 76   ‘The Heart o' Mid-Lothian’ is gaunna be acted.

In fact, if you did a careful search of 19th century texts on an engine like Google Books, carefully weeded out all the Italian references and the miscategorized texts, then you would likely only turn up a term borrowed from Italian, the *gonna* or skirt:

> the other, in a plain linen Saxon tunic, and the *gonna* worn on state occasions, to which he seemed unfamiliar, but with heavy gold bracelets on his arms, long haired and bearded, was Vebba, the Kentish thegn, who had served as nuncius from Godwin to Edward. (Edward Bulwer Lytton, *[Lord Lytton's Novels](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lord_Lytton_s_novels/pkxMAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22gonna%22%20Lytton&pg=PA186&printsec=frontcover)*, ~1850)

There is nothing in Dickens or other 19th century others I tried to suggest *gonna* was extant in Victorian dialogue.

### Research into *Going to* and *Gonna*

Comments have indicated that pronunciation (e.g., /'ɡənə/) may precede *gonna* as a spelling and be present in the mid-19th century. I agree that, in general, pronunciation would logically precede the first instance in spelling. However, there is an absence of evidence that a pronunciation like /ɡənə/ was widespread in the 19th century.

One clue is when *going to* grew in popularity. As linguist [Christian Mair (2004)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287724976_Corpus_linguistics_and_grammaticalisation_theory_Statistics_frequencies_and_beyond#pf9) points out, *going to* exploded in frequency at the turn of the 20th century, at which point *gonna* shows up in the frequency chart:

[image]

Nonstandard pronunciations are more likely to develop as usage becomes more frequent.

We might also ask what *kind* of reduction we would've seen in the mid 19th century, since several forms might be possible. [David Lorenz (2012)](https://d-nb.info/1122646666/34), in studying English semi-modals like *gonna*, makes the point that other reduced forms of *going to* appear before *gonna* in the Corpus of Historical American English (COHA) (p. 114-115). Lorenz cites *goin to*, *gwine to*, and *gon to* occurring in 19th century American English (1827, 1834, and 1886, respectively). These forms may be evidence of progressive reduction, or the idea that over time *going to* lost some of its phonemes to become *gonna* (p. 19):

[image]

What might we hear in London in the mid-19th century? Maybe all of those! It's possible that the reduced sound most common in London dialects in the mid 19th century would have still had a /t/ or /d/ sound in some form or a less reduced vowel. It is also possible that the shift seen in Scottish English also appeared in London English. But it's all speculation. There isn't evidence to support or explicitly forbid the possibility of *gonna*.

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree. Etymon says that the representation 'gonna', _not_ the sound it attempts to convey, dates to the 19th century. We'll be saying histories of the Roman occupation of Britain written in modern English are anachronistic.

Comment: Colloquial usage is **always** in common parlance for a long time before someone tries to emulate it using the impoverished resources of English spelling. Of course, as soon as it gets printed it gets imitated and scorned, and the actual speech continues varying regardless.

Comment: Sweeney Todd is written in modern English not 18th century.